# Displaying Image or Nothing in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image

I have a model with a Boolean checkbox, and when it is clicked 'true' I would like to display the image, and if not clicked 'null' would like to display absolutely nothing.

So far the view is called as:

```
<%= image_tag(@dining.pets? ? 'petfriendly.png' : '', :title => 'Pet Friendly', :alt => 'Pet Friendly') %>
```

The empty tick '' was my attempt at nothing, but it just gives me a broken link image. As this is my personal attempt at working this out and I'm relatively new to rails, I am not sure if an if/else in long form is a good way to go about this?

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a tad shorter syntax.

`<%= image_tag('petfriendly.png',  :title => 'Pet Friendly', :alt => 'Pet Friendly') if @dining.pets.present? %>`

Also, nice use of :alt attribute; the seeing impaired will appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you Andrew- yes, alt tabs are a good habit. Thank you for the response! Worked fine!

Answer (score 4):

try something like

```
<%= @dining.pets.present? ? image_tag('petfriendly.png') : '' %>
```

Comment: Good answer. We also often use a default image in such cases to preserve layout.

Comment: Thanks for this response. see @Andrew Kuklewicz answer below as the one I went with, just as it displays more of a accessible option with attributes that are user frienldy. Yours works just the same. Thanks!

Comment: i was convinced that you will be able to make the transfer to include title and alt tags yourself :p

Comment: agreed frank - they are essentially the same, I just prefer the other syntax.  I actually +1'd your answer before posting mine as it is obviously correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
<%= image_tag('petfriendly.png') if @dining.pets %>
```